# Poisson conditional sum

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, poisson-distribution

Let $N \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ r.v. independent $\{X_k, k = 1, 2, \ldots\}$, such that are independent with each other and $P(X_k = 1) = 1 - P(X_k = 0) = p \in (0, 1)$. Let define $K =\sum_{i=1}^{N}
X_i$.
Calculate

$P[K=k|N=n]$, and

$P[N=n|K=k]$.

For the first part I did the following: I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i \sim Bin(n,p)$

$$P[K=k|N=n]=P\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i=k\right]=\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}.$$

But I got stuck in the second exercise, I tried with Bayes theorem but I do not how to conclude.
Is this right? Any help?

Comment: Clearly you get $0$ if $n < k$.  Otherwise, you get $P[N=n\mid K=k] = \frac{P[N=n, K=k]}{P[K=k]}=\frac{P[K=k\mid N=n]P(N=n)}{P[K=k]}$

Comment: Yes, the problem I had with that expression is $P[K=k]$, maybe with a conditional probability and an infinite sum? I mean $P[K=k]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P[K=k|N=n]$ ?

Comment: It would be better to say $P[K=k]=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}P[K=k, N=n]=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}P[K=k\mid N=n] P[N=n]$.  It is then not difficult to show if $N$ is Poisson with rate $\lambda$ then $K$ is Poisson with rate $\lambda p$

Comment: Yes, my bad. It was the intersection with the sample space... Thanks